# How to move Trash bookmark to the bottom in Thunar?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, xfce4, thunar

I've installed Arch Linux and Xfce. In Thunar, which is default file manager for Xfce, I add a lot of folders to bookmarks. I want to move Trash shortcut to the bottom of bookmarks in Thunar.

P.S: I've noticed that I can't remove Trash, Home and Desktop bookmarks. How to remove them?

Comment: Your note in P.S. is different from the question. Do you want to move Trash bookmark, or entirely remove it? I have a workaround if you just need to have Trash bookmark at bottom in Thunar.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the panel in thunar where the directories are, and you can uncheck the directories if you don't want to show them.

> There is a hidden menu to hide Shortcuts in the Side Pane.
>
> Right click in the Side Pane where there are no shortcuts, like on the
>   DEVICES section label. Then you will get a pop-up menu where you can
>   uncheck items you do not want displayed.

Quote taken from [arch's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Thunar).